# How to start a clean publishing instance and sync everything including OSGi bundles?

Tags: osgi, aem

There are two publishing instances and one is recently down. An advice is to start a clean publishing instance and let the sync happen automatically.

The situation is, two publishing instances are not clustered now and there are quite a few bundles installed.

My question is, if I try to start a clean publishing instance as advised, do I need to do anything to make it exactly the same as the running one? like the followings:

1. republish the pages
2. manually install OSGi bundles
3. configure publishing agent (if url and port number remains the same)

Anything is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not far off in my opinion.

Some minor additions:

- You don't need to install the site-specific osgi bundles manually,
  you can replicate them (after configuring the replication agent) from
  the author instance.
- Re-Publish the pages using tree-activiation.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, mish. One more question, if we are trying to duplicate an existing publishing instance, i.e. start a new instance from an online tar, what are the steps to follow?

Comment: I'd just execute the quickstart jar - once it finishes installing shut it down again - and edit the start script to make it a publish instance. start it again (using the modified start script), and start the replication process from the author instance.

Comment: how to replicate bundles with replication agents?

Comment: @DonaldZhao you can select replicate from the context menu of the package in the package manager